# What is Big O of this longest common subsequence algo

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Solving for this: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-subsequence/
I realize I can use memoization but what is the big O of this brute force algo? I think its O(mnk) where m is length of text1 and n is length of text2 and k is longest common subsequence. Is this analysis right?

```
public int longestCommonSubsequence(String text1, String text2, int index1, int index2) {
        int max1= 0;
        for(int i = index1; i < text1.length(); i++) {
            for(int j = index2; j < text2.length(); j++) {
                if(text1.charAt(i) == text2.charAt(j)) {
                    max1 = Math.max(1 + longestCommonSubsequence(text1, text2, i+1, j+1), max1);
                }
            }
        }
        return max1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your analysis is definitely not right. The running time is nowhere near as low as `O(mnk)`.

Since the function is recursive and many of the recursive calls are with the same parameters, a convenient method of analysis is to count the time spent not in recursive calls, then count the number of recursive calls *for each set of arguments*, and then take the sum over the former multiplied by the latter.

More concretely, let `S(m, n, i, j)` be the time spent not in recursive calls, `C(m, n, i, j)` be the number of times the function is called with those arguments, and call the running time for the overall algorithm `T(m, n)`. Then:

[image: formula for total time]

Let's consider only the worst case, when every character is the same so that the `if` condition in the inner loop is always true:

- The algorithm has a nested loop which iterates `(m - i) * (n - j)` times and does `Θ(1)` work (excluding recursive calls) per iteration, so `S ∈ Θ(mn)` for most of the terms in this formula.
- Much worse, `C` grows [very quickly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion). Roughly, `C` is a combinatorial function which counts all distinct sequences of pairs such that the sequence starts with `(0, 0)` and ends with `(i, j)`, and the intermediate terms are monotonically increasing in both components.

It is hard to tell exactly how fast `C` grows as a function of `i` and `j`, but it's definitely at least exponential. This can be seen by just considering the case where `i = j` and the sequence terms are all like `(k, k)`; even amongst just those sequences, the number of combinations is `2^(i-1)` because sequences of that form correspond with subsets of `{1, ..., i-1}`.

Comment: I'd say in that worst case, where everything leads to a recursive call, you can just attribute the S cost to the C cost instead. And C looks interesting: https://repl.it/repls/PettyCleanVirtualmachines

Comment: @HeapOverflow In the special case where the non-recursive work is asymptotically the same as the number of recursive calls, I suppose you are right.

Comment: Hmm... it's Pascal's triangle, rotated 45 degrees! I will have to think about why, though. The "two from the previous row" rule for Pascal's triangle would come from doing only recursive calls on `(i, j+1)` and `(i+1, j)`, so there must be some reason that the nested loop is equivalent to that.

Comment: hmm I rethought my question and I think you are right that its exponential. You can replace the second loop with m recursive calls where m is the length of the second string. so therefore O(m^(l-i)) for every character j in the first string. O(n * m^l-i) ... something along those lines

Comment: For m=n and the worst case, it appears to be O(4^n): https://repl.it/repls/ModernBurdensomeMicrobsd (So maybe O(2^(m+n) for the general shape.)